# Climbing stairs up to 8 story to reduce weight?

Tags: weight-loss, stairs

Well. Now i have put on a lot. I used to be 65 Kg. Three years back. But now i am 95 Kg. i do not have much time for exercise. I have started in taking healthy food. which includes Vegetables, milk, Oats, multi grain stuff etc.

Moreover i am climbing stairs from ground floor to 8th floor up and down twice a day.

Will this practice reduce my weight ?

Also should i avoid climbing stairs after having lunch ?

Comment: While being active is definitely better than doing nothing, is there any reason you can't find time to exercise?

Comment: Well. I am a full time programmer. Also i do 40 hrs. per week freelancing as well. so finding time is hard for me.. :(

Comment: Well, keeping fit is a matter of priority. Fit people are active people. Even if you lose weight with any gimmicky weight loss program, you'll gain it back if you aren't active. Diligence in using the stairs daily is good; however, you'll need to do more to lose significantly more. There are many answers on here on how to be active. Find time to peruse the answers to obtain tips on how to add activities to your current schedule :).

Comment: There's no much time for exercise is not an excuse. You can always have time to exercise 10mins of intense cardio will suffice. And eating healthy food is not enough to lose weight, track your calorie intake too.

Comment: Well, thank you for your comments and suggestions...will try to find time for me as well....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12 stairs * 8 floors * .17 calorie = 16.32 calories burnt climbing up 8 floors. 
You can take 10 as the approximate count while going down the stairs. 
This way, you will lose around `32.64+ 20 =52.64 calories` in total per day. Now if you body requirement is 2000 calories per day, and you take 2000 calorie diet, it will take you 67 days to lose one kg.

As far as climbing the stairs after eating food is concerned, you should avoid any rigorous exercise immediately after the meals. As our body pumps a lot of blood to intensities, in order to digest the food eaten. So if we exercise, the blood flow will be sent to your legs and any other organ being used. Anyways, a mild walk after the lunch won't hurt.

Comment: Well sounds pretty much detailed. Thank you for the explanation. Well is the climbing stairs that much going to help me in reducing bally fat. ???

Comment: @AmanArora: I assume you calculated the energy it would take like we all learned in physics class. The human body is pretty inefficient at moving stuff, though, so it's probably many times as much due to swaying side to side, stabilizing, swinging arms etc.

Comment: @MayankPathak well the fat doesn't get reduced from a particular spot. It will be reduced from full body including your belly fat as well. And climbing stairs might help but if you are serious you need to increase your anaerobic activities like running, and other forma of cardio.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla True. And more importantly, the calories lost depend on your heart health, body weight, height and its actually quite complex to measure. But we can still have an approximation based on the general data available.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla: Aman Arora likely got it from https://www.stepjockey.com/content/docs/Stair_Climbing_Facts_StepJockey.pdf or from the same source they got it from. They do provide a downward stepping figure as well of .05 calories per step.

Comment: Please tell me on what basis you have taken 0.17 calorie per stair-step? Kindly let me know where I'm wrong in my following calculations---
Energy loss per kg per meter of height = 9.8 Joule /kg.m 1 step = 15 cm = 0.15 m So, energy loss per kg per stair-step = 9.8×0.15 = 1.47 Joule/kg.step where 1 Joule = 1/4.18 calorie Means, energy loss per kg per stair-step = 0.35 calorie/kg.step If two neighbouring floors are 16 stair-steps apart, then the energy loss per floor per kg = 0.35×16 calorie/kg.floor Now the final one, a person weighing 65 kg climbing 8 floors will lose
0.35 × 16 × 65 × 8 = 2912

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was 85 kg when I broke my leg and 1.5 years later I was 110 kg. I had an office job. In the morning, I ate as much as I could. After work, I walked 1 hour (not more). After a few weeks, 1.5 hours per day, and it went better.  In the afternoon, I ate whatever I wanted because I did not eat much in the evening, and, after a time, my body began to get used to it. I lost 4 kg in 1 month, and, after 2 months, a total of 10 kg (do not know if it's healthy). I replaced drinks with water. And reduced bad things like candy, choco, fastfood.  It's only the beginning that's hard.

Remember, if you want to quit, why you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary weight loss will be from your caloric intake. If you are taking in less than you are burning, you will lose weight. There are plenty of [calculators](http://www.caloriecontrol.org/calculator/weight-maintenance-calculator-men) out there to find the figures you need for consumption. Exercise, by itself, does not burn that many calories overall. Sure, run for 20 minutes and you'll manage to burn 400 calories or so, but you get that in a breakfast sandwich, and it's really easy, if you're not counting things out, to eat more than you're burning. The primary benefit of exercise is that, at a certain level of moderate exercise, the body processes food more efficiently, which reduces the health impact of things like eating more fat in your diet, or trying to survive on a restricted diet such as the vegan ones.

For stair-climbing itself, the figures vary. Aman Arora is quoting from an article named [Twenty Amazing Stair Climbing Facts](https://www.stepjockey.com/content/docs/Stair_Climbing_Facts_StepJockey.pdf) by Stepjockey. [Articles at Livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/298903-calories-burned-walking-up-stairs/) come up with slightly different figures. Ultimately, I'd advise assuming that you burn maybe 100 calories from it, and to focus on a small caloric reduction in your food intake with whatever gives you mild exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You need to check your foods that you consume. Start eliminating the fats/calories contains food first. And climbing stairs is a good exercise, you need to do it regularly. along with you should start walking for at least half an hour a day. Then, you will definitely start loosing weight.